# MVC - Passing a string on button click after the View is loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC so apologies if the question is silly.

I have the below View

[image]

which renders as :

[image]

Now what I need is when I click the View Status button, it should pass the Student Id to the controller Action which then checks from DB if the Student is Full time/Part Time and return a simple string that goes against the Status at the end.

Can someone please help me with two things:

1. How do I pass the Id parameter
2. How do I pass the string value back and render

Below is the Controller method:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just like other action links in your sample, use HtmlHelper for the View link too, and you can pass your Id parameter (1)

```
@Html.ActionLink("View","View", new {id = item.SutdentId});
```

you may return View or PartialView to show the details of the student (2). but if you will just return a string value to the client, ajax request is better.

```
public ActionResult View(int id)
{
   return View("yourViewName", model:id); 
   //or get your student from any datasource and pass your student object as model
}
```